# What is the solution when a user want to register with a previously authenticated phone number using Firebase Authentication for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am confused about which firebase authentication method should I use for my app. I know it's easy to implement and also easy for users to register using their phone numbers. The issue I see, using the phone number is that these days users are changing their mobile numbers and the mobile operators are giving the same number to a new customer. So, as you know, it's not safe only to rely on phone authentication. So, what I have been thinking is to let the user register with their phone number and then create a username of their choice and use the username as the login credentials.

But, again, what to do if a new user wants to register with a mobile number that was previously used by one of my users? Is it possible for the new user to register with a previously used mobile number for phone authentication?

And what to do if the user wants to change his number? Suppose a user register with mobile number 123 and created an account, he then wants to change his number to 567. Is it possible to change?
My question might sound stupid or silly, but the reason I am asking this is that I don't see any option to edit it here manually.

[image]

What is the best way to handle it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you don't think that method is secure enough, why enable it at all?  There's other methods of authentication.

Comment: I agree with @GabeSechan reply. If you know mobile number can't remain a unique id for the user, then you must not use it. Using it will just create an extra step of redirection. There is an option to always send otp for logging the user in. If the user is having the sim, they will get the otp else they won't be able to use it. You can set a time to live for the token for a defined time period to avoid sending multiple messages. I suggest use an email or a username as that will remain unique to the user instead of the mobile number.